# Is the version of the Dynamic Web Module facet the same as the servlet version?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, gradle

We are setting the version of the jst.web facet using Gradle as such:

```
eclipse {
    wtp{ 
        facet {
            facet name: 'java', version: '1.7'
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: '2.5'
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the version number `'2.5'`. Does this version number reflect the version of the Servlet API supported by the project or is it the version of the facet itself?

What I want to do is pull the versions into variables like so:

```
eclipse {
    wtp{ 
        facet {
            facet name: 'java', version: javaVersion
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: servletVersion
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if `servletVersion` is an accurate name (it would also be used to specify the `providedCompile` version of the servlet API). Is it possible that the version of the facet is different from the version of the Servlet API used by the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's analogous to the Servlet specification version you're requiring.